# Append Variable to NSURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to make a phone call link out of a phone number coming from JSON, Its throwing an uncaught exception on this line:

```
 lblPhone.text = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://" URLByAppendingPathComponent:phone]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a label's string out of an action that doesn't return a string. The text of the string can't be set from the result of the action of trying to make a phone call.

To create the label, just use the telephone number.

```
lblPhone.text = phone
```

To make the call, you need to hook up an action that uses the label:

```
NSString *phoneNrUrl = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:lblPhone.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNrUrl]];
```

You could do the above two lines as a single line, but I prefer readability and letting the compiler do the optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function `+[NSURL URLWithString:URLByAppendingPathComponent:]` which doesn't exist. You want to first create the URL from the string, and then add the path component.

Something more like this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"] URLByAppendingPathComponent:phone]];
```

Comment: Thanks, still didnt work, same error as posted on other answer.

Comment: You're trying to set a label from a method that makes a phone call.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that too. Changed my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that `openURL:` returns a `BOOL` and `lblPhone.text` seems more an `NSString`.

If that's not the reason, what about adding the exception message to your question?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSURL URLWithString:stringByAppendingString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x41de40'

Comment: That error is caused when you use a function that doesn't exist. Look at my answer - you're pulling two functions together.

Comment: Tom is right. I didn't scroll your code. Fix that and you'll hit a second exception. Then read my answer.